# C: Extra output in printf

Tags: c

I've just started to learn C programming last week and I've learnt about some basics about it. So now I'm trying to make a program which can add up two numbers and show the result.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int result;

    printf("Insert a number:%d\n");
    scanf ("%d",&a);

    printf ("Insert the next number:%d\n");
    scanf ("%d",&b);

    result = a + b;

    printf ("Result is:%d\n",result);
    return 0;

}
```

It can be compiled and run but the following result is shown.
 [1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xjdv.png

Can someone please help me to get rid of that 4200612, which is output at the first `printf` statement? Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: By removing the unnecessary `%d` from the first 2 `printf` statements, which have no corresponding argument so they print junk.

Comment: "the following result is shown". What result?

Comment: Please follow site-rules and post text as text, not images!

Comment: @J.Yang I suggest you spend an hour reading the man page for `printf` since you will be using it and its derivatives *a lot*. Though due to its complexity, that is barely sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of `%d` in first two `printf` statement.

```
printf("Insert a number: ");
scanf ("%d",&a);
printf ("Insert the next number: ");
scanf ("%d",&b);
```

Since there is no corresponding argument. It will print some random value.

Comment: Okay, got it now. Thanks! And may i ask what's the difference between %d and %f?

Comment: @J.Yang : `%d` and `%f` are used to read and write and integer and floating point number respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the extra %d's in your printfs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int result;

    printf("Insert a number:\n");
    scanf ("%d",&a);

    printf ("Insert the next number:\n");
    scanf ("%d",&b);

    result = a + b;

    printf ("Result is:%d\n",result);
    return 0;

}
```